# R occurrences of word in Character list

Tags: r

I have a character list filled with years

```
: chr "2010"
: chr "2011"
: chr "2010"
: chr "2012"
```

and I want the occurences of each year, so for the above I would have

```
"2010", 2
"2011", 1
"2012", 1
```

Like what I would expect to get from the `table` command. How can I get counts of each word in my character list?

Comment: In r studio it describes it as a "List of 1000"

Comment: list("2010", "2012", "2011")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 table(unlist(lst))
 #  2010 2011 2012 
 #  1    1    1
```

Or `count` from `plyr`

```
 library(plyr)
 count(unlist(lst))
 #     x freq
 #1 2010    1
 #2 2011    1
 #3 2012    1
```

#### data

```
 lst <- list("2010", "2012", "2011")
```